# How do I access the Documents folder of an iPhone application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, documents

I'm trying to back up the save file of a video game.  I'm pretty sure the save data is stored in /Documents because the folder's "last updated" time stamp changes every time I complete a level.  Yet when I open /Documents using iExplorer, iFunBox, et al, it's empty.  When I try to copy the entire folder to my desktop computer, it shows up as an empty folder.

I think some setting is preventing me from viewing the internals of that folder.  How can I get around this without jailbreaking my phone?  Thanks.

I'm using an iPhone 4 (2010) with iOS 7, if it matters.

I'm not an app developer and I have no knowledge of Objective-C. I'm just trying to backup save data for a video game I'm playing. For example, Candy Crush Saga stores save files in Apps/Candy Crush/Documents/Save_########.dat. Other apps also store save files in their respective /Documents folders but I'm not seeing anything inside of them.

Comment: Have you tried to check from XCode Windows Menu -> Devices -> Select Device -> Select your app -> Select "Show container" ? It will show you all sandboxed files related to your app.

Comment: I do not understand why somebody downvoted your question. Depends how you saved your settings. The Documents folder contains files you created (including SQLite related files). NSUserDefaults settings are located at /Bundle/Library/Preferences/bundelid.plist so it is normal to have an empty Document folder.

Comment: I'm not an app developer and I have no knowledge of Objective-C.  I'm just trying to backup save data for a video game I'm playing.  For example, Candy Crush Saga stores save files in Apps/Candy Crush/Documents/Save_########.dat.  Other apps also store save files in their respective /Documents folders but I'm not seeing anything inside of them.

Comment: you should mention in question itself that you are not an ios developer :-)

Answer (score 0):

The question is lacking any code but it seems that you are not accessing an allowable directory.

iOS apps are restricted in file system access as a security measure. The directory you most likely should use is the NSDocumentDirectory accessed via an API.

Example access code:

Objective-C:

```
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
```

Swift:

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
```

Comment: I'm not an app developer and I have no knowledge of Objective-C. I'm just trying to backup save data for a video game I'm playing. For example, Candy Crush Saga stores save files in Apps/Candy Crush/Documents/Save_########.dat. Other apps also store save files in their respective /Documents folders but I'm not seeing anything inside of them.

Comment: swift 3 - How to get path upto 'Documents/Inbox/', because access file from 'inbox' directory.